# CRM 2011 Get Required and Optional Contact Names from ActivityPartySet

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am trying to create a report in SSRS for CRM 2011 and I am trying to get information from the AppointmentSet. I am able to get everything expect the Required and Optional Attendees. I'm pretty sure the AppointmentSet links to the ActivityPartySet to for the attendees. But I am not sure. How would you go about getting the required attendees and optional attendees. This is what I have so far.

```xml
<fetch>
      <entity name="appointment">
        <attribute name="scheduledstart" />
        <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="ownerid">
            <attribute name="firstname" alias="ownerFirstName" />
            <attribute name="lastname" alias="ownerLastName" />
        </link-entity>
        <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="new_contactperson">
            <attribute name="parentcustomerid" alias="parentaccount" />
            <attribute name="new_businessunit" alias="businessunit" />
        </link-entity>
        <attribute name="new_contactperson" />
        <attribute name="subject" />
        <attribute name="new_coldernotes" />
        <link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid">
        <attribute name="participationtypemask" alias="participationtypemask" />
        </link-entity>
      </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully clear on your requirements but the following snippet will return full details of Optional or Required attendees, but only if they are system user records. If the parties contain other record types then no results are returned...

```
<entity name='appointment'>
    <attribute name='subject'/>
    <attribute name='actualend'/>
    <attribute name='actualstart'/>
    <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='activityid' operator='eq' value='MyActivityGuid'/>
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='activityparty' from='activityid' to='activityid'>
        <attribute name='partyidname'/>
        <attribute name='participationtypemask'/>
        <attribute name='activityid'/>
        <attribute name='activitypartyid'/>
        <attribute name='addressused'/>         
        <attribute name='participationtypemaskname'/>
        <attribute name='partyid'/>
        <attribute name='partyiddsc'/>
        <attribute name='partyobjecttypecode'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespecid'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespeciddsc'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespecidname'/>
        <attribute name='scheduledend'/>
        <attribute name='scheduledstart'/>
        <filter type='and'/>
        <filter type='or'>
            <condition attribute='participationtypemaskname' operator='eq' value='Optional attendee'/>
            <condition attribute='participationtypemaskname' operator='eq' value='Required attendee'/>
        </filter>
        <link-entity name='systemuser' from='systemuserid' to='partyid'>
            <attribute name='fullname'/>
        </link-entity>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
```

Otherwise if you omit the entire final `link-entity` node for `systemuser` you can see the `addressused` attribute which contains an email address. I.e.:

```
<entity name='appointment'>
    <attribute name='subject'/>
    <attribute name='actualend'/>
    <attribute name='actualstart'/>
    <filter type='and'>
        <condition attribute='activityid' operator='eq' value='MyActivityGuid'/>
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='activityparty' from='activityid' to='activityid'>
        <attribute name='partyidname'/>
        <attribute name='participationtypemask'/>
        <attribute name='activityid'/>
        <attribute name='activitypartyid'/>
        <attribute name='addressused'/>         
        <attribute name='participationtypemaskname'/>
        <attribute name='partyid'/>
        <attribute name='partyiddsc'/>
        <attribute name='partyobjecttypecode'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespecid'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespeciddsc'/>
        <attribute name='resourcespecidname'/>
        <attribute name='scheduledend'/>
        <attribute name='scheduledstart'/>
        <filter type='and'/>
        <filter type='or'>
            <condition attribute='participationtypemaskname' operator='eq' value='Optional attendee'/>
            <condition attribute='participationtypemaskname' operator='eq' value='Required attendee'/>
        </filter>
    </link-entity>
</entity>
```

Does this help?